# NDSolve with embedded piecewise function for state-variable

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, piecewise

Given ODE:

$\dot{x}=-2 e^{-x^2} x + U$

**where:**

$U=-u_{as}$

$u_{as} = \begin{cases} \frac{e}{\psi_+-e}, & \mbox{if } e\mbox{>=0} \\ \frac{e}{e-\psi_-}, & \mbox{if } e\mbox{<0} \end{cases}$

$e=x$

$\psi_+=\frac{1-\delta}{T \cdot t+1}+\delta$

$\psi_-=-\frac{0.5+\delta}{3T \cdot t+1}-\delta$

*There is my code:*

```
(***)

Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1/4, xe = 1, T = 5, \[Delta] = 0.1}

e = x[t]

\[Psi]plus = (1 - \[Delta])/(T t + 1) + \[Delta]

\[Psi]minus = -(1/2 + \[Delta])/(3 T t + 1) - \[Delta]

uas = Piecewise[{{e/(\[Psi]plus - e), e >= 0}, {e/(e - \[Psi]minus), 
    e < 0}}]

U = -uas

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -2 E^-x[t]^2 x[t] + U, x[0] == xs}, {x}, {t, 
   0, 3}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], \[Psi]plus, \[Psi]minus}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 100]

Plot[{Evaluate[U /. sys]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

When I run `NDSolve`, I get a error on the 3rd second of the calculation.

```
`NDSolve::smpf: Failure to project onto the discontinuity surface when computing Filippov continuation at time 2.359060463990643.
```

I want to understand what the reason for this error is and how to avoid it in the numerical calculations.

I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: It looks like a numerical  problem at `t=2.35`. Decrease the  range `{t, 0, 2.35}` and `NDSolve` evaluates without error message

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, if we reduce the time interval of the calculation. But I need calculation at large intervals {t, 0,100} and above. It is necessary to correct the error and avoid it in the future.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The problem disappeared when I added to the code `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`. 

But I still did not understand what was the reason for the error.

Comment: Try `AccuracyGoal -> 32` or even `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity`.

Comment: +1. Consider reporting it to WRI support. I feel there is room for improvement here.  There's no real discontinuity in the vector field, just a suspected one arising from `Piecewise`.  But the vector field changes continuously as crosses the equilibrium  $x=0$.  I suspect it's this singularity in the vector field at the boundary between the pieces that leads to the failed projection.  (Raising `AccuracyGoal` keeps the numerical solution from crossing the boundary, and the true solution does not cross it either.)

Answer (score 2):

Extended comment, not an answer:

Perhaps `StreamPlot` shows you the reason:

```
StreamPlot[{1, -2 E^-x ^2 x  - 
Which[x >= 0, x /(0.1` + (0.9`/(1 + 5 t)) - x ),x < 0, x /(0.1` + (0.6`/(1 + 15 t)) + x ), True, 0]}, {t, 0,5}, {x, -.5, .5}]
```

[image]

The trajectory `x->0` seems to be unstable!

Comment: The problem disappeared when I added to the code Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}.

Comment: Yes that's already clear. Trajectory `x~0` isn't attractive, because of the discontinuity of the ode near `x~0`

Comment: Ok, so the reason is internal, not algorithmic.

Comment: The reason is your discontinuous ode near `x==0`. `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`seems to ignore this fact!

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: You might want to zoom the plot domain on in on `{t, x} == {2.4, 0}`.  Can't trust blank spots on `StreamPlot`.  It a finicky function. (You'd probably be interested in my comments above, too.)